# Generate a navigation from sections and slides with js

Tags: javascript, arrays, children, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js and want to build navigation automatically when I ad a section or a slide. Therefore I need the id from the sections. Which I have in the script below. But I also need a data-anchor nested in the slide div's inside each section.

**Goal: the html structure is driven by fullpage.js. al working fine. But now I want to automatically generate a submenu for the slides. Therefor I need the id from the section. (which is done) And the value from the data-anchor to put into the href. so the href src needs to be =section0/about and section0/history. when I add a slide in the section it should automatically put a link in the nav. **

Anyone?

HTML

```
    <div id="fullpage">
      <div id="section0"></div>
      <div id="section1">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="about"></div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="history"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2"></div>
      <div id="section3"></div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var sections =  $('#fullpage > div').map(function(){
      return '#' + this.id;
    }).get();
    });
```

RESULT MENU

```
    <ul id="subnav" class="innernav">
     <li class="subnav"><a href="#section1/about">About</a></li>
     <li class="subnav"><a href="#section1/history">History</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Edit**
Does my explanation make any sense?

Comment: I do not understand 90% of what you are saying in your description. Can you try to put it in simple to understand terms, what do you want to do is what i need to know, not what you have.

Comment: try `return "#" + this.id` instead of 2 `.map`s

Comment: Thx Rajesh, I will modify

Comment: Dellirium, I adjusted my explanation. Hope this does it for you?

Comment: I tried to do a map function on the idBuild function (now adjusted to var sections), but that did not return anything

Comment: You want an array of element ids, or you want to automatically create a table of contents, with links to the relevant slides/sections? You've shown the HTML you're starting with, it might be useful to show the HTML you want to end up with.

Comment: This is the html I want to end up with. I'll add what I want to get. just a sec

Comment: So links to the slides indeed

Comment: Is this clear in any way?